# os.system() returning False for some reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have a rather large program (memory-wise), it's a neural network with Tensorflow. I'm working with volumetric data. My end goal is to use `ffmpeg` to create a video through the volume -- where each frame is a z-slice. I've successfully done this before using the `os` python library. The code looks like this:

```
videoFile = self.slicesPath + "/0.mp4"
sliceFiles = self.slicesPath + "/%04d.jpg"
os.system("ffmpeg -y -framerate 10 -start_number 0 -i " + sliceFiles + " -vcodec mpeg4 " + videoFile)
```

When I step through this with `pdb` and I try to execute the `os.system()` command I get `-1` as if there were some error.

```
(Pdb) os.system("ffmpeg -y -framerate 10 -start_number 0 -i " + sliceFiles + " -vcodec mpeg4 " + videoFile)
-1
```

So then I printed the two variables...

```
(Pdb) sliceFiles
'/home/volcart/UnsupervisedResults/HercFragment/VAE/0/1/%04d.jpg'
(Pdb) videoFile
'/home/volcart/UnsupervisedResults/HercFragment/VAE/0/1/0.mp4'
```

Opened up a python console in a new terminal tab, copy and pasted the exact same line of code (with the strings above instead of variable names), and BAM! it magically works.

Why is this? It works in a separate python console, it works in bash, but it doesn't work inside my program (when it is the exact same thing). My only guess is something to do with memory, but I know for certain I am not out of memory... my machine has 64GB and python has no limits.

**EDIT**

I just tried a `subprocess` instead and got this:

```
(Pdb) subprocess.call("ffmpeg -y -framerate 10 -start_number 0 -i " + sliceFiles + " -vcodec mpeg4 " + videoFile, shell=True)
*** OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

But how is it unable to allocate memory? Python doesn't have memory bounds right? I have 64GB of memory, and I can execute the `ffmpeg` command outside the program, so something is bounding my program.

Comment: Perhaps `subprocess.check_output` would give you more useful diagnostic information.

Comment: What does `os.system('echo $PATH')` give you, and is it the same as running `echo $PATH` at the shell?

Comment: @Kevin check my **EDIT**

Comment: That's pretty peculiar. Why would ffmpeg, a program written in in C, be emitting OSError, a Python exception? Something strange is going on here...